# Jboss Fuse tooling issue with routes imported from other xml

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, jboss-developer-studio

I am using Jboss developer studio Version: 10.4.0.GA.I have imported Routes From Other XML Files using the  in the main camel-context.xml and defining the routes in a seperate xml file inside .Iam able to see the design view of the xml defined in camel-context.xml in fuse tooling.But iam not able to see the design view of the routeContext xml it is blank in design view, but the source has the xml.

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade to Dev Studio 11.1? It has some improvements regarding JBoss Fuse Tooling that may help your case.

Comment: I tested in 11.0 as well it is not working.it seems Dev Studio  11.1 was released two days back are you sure this issue is fixed?

Comment: No, I'm not sure. But in my case this version resolved a lot of cumbersome bugs. You may fill a JIRA regarding this matter and get a answer from the engineers: https://issues.jboss.org/projects/JBIDE

Comment: Hello,I tested with 11.1 as well still the issue persists.

Comment: Please open a JIRA on the link I posted in my last comment and attach your project to be used as a reproducer. :)

Comment: prefer to use https://issues.jboss.org/projects/FUSETOOLS tracker fro Fuse Tooling features even if issues created in https://issues.jboss.org/projects/JBIDE are monitored and will not be lost and will be redirected to the specific FUSE Tooling tracker.

Comment: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/FUSETOOLS-2644 is raised,thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood well, you are using routeContext tag, right?

If yes, this is not supported. Please open a Feature request on https://issues.jboss.org/projects/FUSETOOLS

Regards,

EDIT: it has been implemented and will be available in next release planned for end of January, see https://issues.jboss.org/browse/FUSETOOLS-2644